# How to use Cloudflare and how it is different from Pinata

Tags: cloudflare, ipfs

For my IPFS server, I use pinata.cloud and upload my content there. But it is slow and I have heard people say that Cloudflare IPFS are faster. But I couldn't find anything on how to upload to Cloudflare IPFS server instead of Pinata.

I might have misunderstood the whole thing. Does it really matter where do I upload my content as long as I upload it to IPFS? Like, is there any difference if I use IPFS desktop or use Pinata to upload my content to IPFS? How is Cloudflare faster then? or is it?